# Getting an exception of "System.Net.WebException"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webclient

I'm facing some weird scenario in my C# application. I have one XML file which has below node.

`<SetupURL> https://xyz/abc.exe </SetupURL>`

Through my C# application, I'm parsing this XML and reading SetupURL node and getting it's value in DownloadFilePath variable.

After reading DownloadFile variable, I'm using `WebClient.DownloadFile(DownloadFilePath, TargetPath)` function to download the file. But I'm getting below error.

> System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Windows\system32\xyz.abc.exe'.  at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

I tried to find out the root cause for why it's adding "C:\Windows\System32" in DownloadFilePath, but I couldn't.

DownloadFilePath and TargetPath are correct. When I tried DownloadFilePath on web browser, it's working. And TargetPath also has the proper directory structure.

Comment: Debug your code. If you get that error, the actual string doesn't start with `https://`.

Comment: probably your DownloadFilePath or TargetPath are wrong.

Comment: I doubt the AppPool has access to `C:\Windows\system32`

Comment: @VDWWD : how to check this ? 
Is this issue related to any IE settings or else ?